# Laravel - mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME, JSON_EXTRACT(HISTOGRAM, '$."number-of-buckets-specified"') COLUMN_STATISTICS

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb

Out of a sudden spatien/laravel-backup started giving issue `Unknown table 'COLUMN_STATISTICS'`

I use laradock (docker for laravel) - mariadb

I alredy tried adding to my.cnf

```
[mysqldump]
column-statistics=0
```

My setup, for reference, is tris https://github.com/laradock/laradock/tree/master/mariadb

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable --column-statistics=0 in config/database.php not in my.conf

```
//config/database.php
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql'
        ...,
        'dump' => [
           'dump_binary_path' => '/path/to/the/binary', // only the path, so without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`
           'use_single_transaction',
           'timeout' => 60 * 5, // 5 minute timeout
           'exclude_tables' => ['table1', 'table2'],
           'add_extra_option' => '--column_statistics=0', // for example '--column_statistics=0'
        ]
    ],
];
```

Reference - https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-backup/v7/installation-and-setup